# Trigger Bootstrap Dropdown via Jquery + Normal Functionality

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

The below code works: when the button is clicked, the dropdown has the class "open" added to it and then shows the dropdown-menu as anticipated.

```
$("#welcome-carousel-button").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".dropdown").addClass("open");    
});
```

However, if I then click the actual dropdown element, the open class is not removed from .dropdown. Only when I click it a second time is the open class removed. I want both my button and the dropdown element to be removing/adding the open class.

I've been playing around with jquery but think changing the bootstrap code would probably be better. Seems likely that it's just a toggle on click that assumes the dropdown begins closed rather than manually checking to see if the class "open" is there or not and then doing the opposite.

However, before I go figure that out I thought I'd check to see if there's a simple jQuery solution I'm missing? Or if anyone already knows the change I'd have to make to the bootstrap code?

Edit:

Removing the Angular controller from the page resolves the issue. No clue as of yet as to why.

Comment: Could we get your html or possibly a fiddle demonstrating the issue to work off of?

Comment: Seems to work with the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/morgwild/GsS5b/); so I probably messed up somewhere else. Good call, KyleMit.

Comment: Glad to be a rubber duck :)

Comment: If you are using AngularJS could you use the ng-click / ng-class directives for this instead of jQuery?

Comment: yea; I was getting it functional in jquery first before moving it over to Angular. But even using ng-click there were issues; taking out Angular (which wasn't 100% necessary for that view ne way) was the quick fix.